# using SDL with STM32F4 on Eclipse (C#)

Tags: c#, sdl, emulation, stm32f4discovery

here's my problem:
I'm doing a NES emulator for STM32F4DISCOVERY, and I almost done but I depende on an extern file (SDL) and I looked for one and found the official page, I downloaded the 2.0 version but my program cant resolve "SDL_HWSURFACE" and "SDL_DOUBLEBUF"

```
gui->screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width * GUI_IMAGE_SCALE,height * GUI_IMAGE_SCALE, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
```

Where can I download the correct one?
(i work on C#)

Answer (score 0):

There's no `SDL_SetVideoMode()` in SDL2.  Use [`SDL_CreateWindow()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) instead.

Comment: thanks, as you said tehre's no SDL_SetVideoMode() in SDL2, but is on SDL1.2.5, thank you